# Origin and exposition $\mathbb N$ can be partitioned into infinitely many subsets $A+b_k$ for some infinite $A$

Tags: number-theory

I came across this fantastic mathematical result and I can't help but think that it's too amazing a result to not have a paper on it or at least be named after somebody ! Unfortunately, the book just presented it as a dull commonplace paragraph that students should be able to solve routinely.

The question is : Is there a way to partition the positive integers into infinitely many infinite subsets such that each subset is generated from any other by adding the same positive integer to each element of the subset.

The proof is strikingly simple.

First we have two sets, $A$ and $B$. $A$ consists of all numbers with zeroes at odd positions and $B$ consists of all numbers with zeroes at even positions. Every positive integer can be uniquely represented as $n = a + b$,$ a \in A, b \in B$. Now, the infinite family of sets are made as follows : $A_1 = A$, $A_k = A + b_k$, where $b_k$ is the $k$-th element of $B$.

Also, if someone could offer further exposition on the proof it would be great. I don't think this proves ANY subset can be generated from any other, just proves that any subset can be generated from one subset.

Now, I want to know who first found this result or if it's really just a commonplace result with nothing special about it

Answer (score 1):

The result isn’t quite true the way you’ve stated it. What is true is that we can partition $\Bbb Z^+$ into infinite sets $A_k$ for $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ so that whenever $k,\ell\in\Bbb Z^+$ and $k\ne\ell$, there is a positive integer $n$ such that **either** $A_k=A_\ell+n$ **or** $A_\ell=A_k+n$. Equivalently, whenever $k,\ell\in\Bbb Z^+$, there is an integer $n$, not necessarily positive, such that $A_\ell=A_k+n$ (and hence $A_k=A_\ell-n$).

The sets $A_k$ defined in your question do indeed satisfy this statement. Suppose that $k$ and $\ell$ are distinct positive integers; without loss of generality we may assume that $b_k<b_\ell$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
A_\ell&=A+b_\ell\\
&=A+b_k+(b_\ell-b_k)\\
&=A_k+(b_\ell-b_k)\;,
\end{align*}$$

where clearly $b_\ell-b_k\in\Bbb Z^+$. In particular, if we enumerate $B=\{b_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ in increasing order, so that $b_k<b_\ell$ whenever $k<\ell$, then we have $A_\ell=A_k+(b_\ell-b_k)$ whenever $k<\ell$.

I grant that the existence of such a partition is at least a little surprising, and it does take a bit of ingenuity (or luck!) to come up with one, but I suspect that this is what mathematicians call a *folklore* result: something that is widely known without being certainly attributable to anyone.

Comment: Why do you say the way I say it is wrong ? I copied it exactly from the book. I think it's because any set cannot be generated from every other set.

Comment: Should I move this to history ?

Comment: @user230452: If that's exactly how the book stated it, the book is wrong. If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\Bbb Z^+$, and $A=B+n$ for some positive integer $n$, then there is no positive integer $m$ such that $B=A+m$, as may be seen by considering the smallest members of $A$ and $B$. There is an integer $m$ such that $B=A+m$, but it's the negative integer $-n$. You can only arrange things so that if $A_k$ and $A_\ell$ are distinct members of the partition, one of them -- the one with the larger smallest member-- is a positive integral translate of the other.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought.

Comment: @user230452: The mathematical part of the question has been answered here, but you could try asking the other part in history. I doubt that anyone will be able to tell you anything concrete, but there's no harm in asking. You might give it a little more time here, though: there are more people here to see it.

Comment: I see that you're a professor. I'm an undergraduate in CS who wants to change to mathematics eventually. Do you think doing contest math problems will help ? Also, can you state this problem in a way that it will be correct and only in words, rather than in symbols ?

Comment: @user230452: Doing contest math problems won't hurt, and to the extent that it gets you to learn some mathematical ideas and gets you accustomed to mathematical reasoning, it can only help. Contest math tends to use a somewhat idiosyncratic part of mathematics, so you'd probably learn more by studying some specific topic on your own, but if you enjoy working on contest problems, the extra motivation may be worth the limited and rather scattershot exposure.

Comment: Give me some tips on becoming a good mathematician.

Comment: @user230452: Is there a way to partition the positive integers into infinitely many infinite subsets in such a way that each of these subsets can be obtained from any other by adding the same non-zero integer to each element of the other subset? This is the question that the author really meant to ask and for which he sketched a proof of an affirmative answer.

Comment: @user230452: I don't know that I really can: different people seem to manage it in different ways. The main prerequisites, I'd say, are a strong interest and a willingness -- even a desire -- to spend time actively thinking about it. (As the old poster said, math is not a spectator sport.) I have to go offline for a few hours now, but I'll check back later.

Comment: Yeah, I study a lot on my own and according to my interest but I don't really like studying for marks so I don't get great marks, even though I may have more knowledge.